# AngularJS reset directive data and refresh the template from main controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here is my directive:

```
app.directive('gwQuestionSet', function (QuestionSetFactory, _) {

    'use strict';
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: '/Classification/templates/question-set.html',
        scope: {
            'gwPlQuestionSet': '='
        },
        controller: ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$http', function ($rootScope, $scope, $http, _) {

            var set = $rootScope.QuestionSets;
            var getquestionSets = QuestionSetFactory.create();

            var questionSets = getquestionSets.getQuestionSetViewModel(set);

            $scope.questionSets = questionSets;

        }]
    };
});
```

My question is if I reset the data of $rootScope.QuestionSets from my main controller, can these code in directive controller be revoked and the template get refreshed?

Comment: The controller part is run only once (when directive is initialized). You can use $watch to bind changes and refresh your data.

Comment: Why are you getting data from `$rootScope`? Data should come from either a directive attribute or a service.

Comment: How to use a service to set data for the directive? We load a JSON file and process it for the template. The file need reload on the event. The template is a little complicated:

Comment: Here is the template: <div ng-repeat="qs in questionSets">
    <div ng-repeat="q in qs.questions">
        <div ng-if="q.aspects.visible">
            <div gw-pl-ctrl-group label="{{q.label | translate}}" model="q">
                <div ng-if="q.type ==='SELECT'">
                    ......